# BlobAccessDenied with Application packages

Tags: azure-batch

I have been having an issue with **application packages** where there will be days/times where I just get a null exit code and **BlobAccessDenied Error** for the exact same application package and exact same command line that previously worked and gave a non-null exit code. For instance, today, I've been getting this error for the exact same packages and commands that I ran yesterday. What am I missing? Or is this a bug in the application packages service? (for VM configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Update:

This fix is been released and deployed, this error will no longer exist for the specified case.

Also something I wrote in an hour jsut to test and might come handy apart from good dotnet samples :

- https://github.com/Tatsinnit/quick_sample_batchapppkgworking
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-batch-samples

Thanks j.B. & Jan